# Can I modify entries in a Pytorch Dataset object?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, graph-neural-network

I've taken code from the Pytorch Geometric website, namely: [link to Pytorch Example Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I8a0DfQ3fI7Njc62__mVXUlcAleUclnb?usp=sharing)

It uses the MUTAG dataset, which has 188 graphs.

I've tried to modify the first 59 graphs to become specific graphs with features and labels that I've created. So effectively I wanted to overwrite the first 59 graphs, then use just the first 59 graphs as my training and test set.

The code did not tell me, but when I checked the outputs of the code it seems my changes did not go through. The way I changed the first 59 graphs was by trying to assign values to the entries as below:

`dataset[58].x = torch.tensor([[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],...])`

`dataset[58].edgeindices = torch.tensor([[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],[1,2,0,3,...]])`

`dataset[58].y = torch.tensor([0])`

In particular, I noticed that the last line of the above code did not go through, that is the value of dataset[58].y remained [1] as in the original dataset, so my assignment to make it [0] above did not go through.

My question is, how would I re-assign the tensors present in the MUTAG dataset so they are my custom graphs?

I have tried to make .csv files and a custom 'Dataset' class, but working with this is producing errors. So I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do the re-assignment above, or if we can go into the MUTAG dataset, download it, change what's in it, then load that into my code.

Edit: I have since found that the entries in a dataset are fixed once you download using TUDataset(). I've found that transforms of the data are possible though. I've created a separate question about how to perform transforms based on the data entry's index. Should I keep updating this post or use the new question?